# Which data structure should I use to represent this data set?

Tags: java, hashmap, pyspark

Suppose I have a data set as follows:

```
Screen ID  User ID
 1          24     
 2          50
 2          80
 3          23
 5          50
 3          60
 6          64
 .          .
 .          .
 .          .
 400,000    200,000
```

and I want to track the screens that each user visited. My first approach would be to create a Hash Map where the keys would be the user ids, and the values would be the screen ids. However, I get an OutofMemory error when using Java. Are there efficient data structures that can handle this volume of data? There will be about 3,000,000 keys and for each key about 1000 values. Would Spark(Python) be the way to go for this? The original dataset has around 300,000,000 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: `map` is efficient, i wonder what is going on with your hardware.

Comment: Have you tried simply increasing the memory available to your JVM via -Xmx before adopting a new structure ? Your original data structure above doesn't seem unreasonable at first sight. Failing that, can you store the data offline ?

Comment: If this doesn't need to be a memory-resident data structure, then you might find that a RDBMS table would suit your needs.  JDBC is your friend.

Comment: Python is a language and not a data-structure

Comment: I agree with @scottb : use a database of some sort - That data is nothing that your application should hold in memory all the time.

Comment: @luk2302 I need to have access to all the data in memory. I am writing  a method that removes a set of screens and calculates the number of impacted users.  I am also writing an optimization method to determine what screens to remove. This would require that the data be in memory

Comment: That is all stuff a database can do for you if you use select and delete properly

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks. I will look into JDBC. One last question. Would you happen to know if the Spark framework would be an ideal framework to use in this case is using a data base just as good? I was thinking this problem is suitable for frameworks that can handle "big data".

Comment: One thing I'm confused about: you say there are 3,000,000 keys but your keys only range from 1 to 400,000. So how can there be 3 million keys?

Comment: With such a large dataset, I think that your insistence that this data *must be* memory resident is unrealistic.  If you are able to define a data set, and then are able to define an operation on that data set, then you can accomplish your goals with SQL.  Otherwise, you're going to be looking at special hardware requirements.

Comment: Spark works well, if your are able to make slices of your input and parallelize the processing. This is obviously the case here. You can divide the data by different users.

Comment: Can you eventually update your question and add: The peace of code that gave the OOM Exception, How you want to access the data. Knowing how the data should be accessed, is critical for selecting the right data structure.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to store such a large data in memory it would be better to store it in data base and use only required data. As using any data structure in any language will consume nearly equal memory.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap will not work with what you're describing as the keys must be unique. Your scenario is duplicating the keys.

If you want to be more memory efficient and don't have access to a relational database or an external file, consider designing something using arrays.

The advantage of arrays is the ability to store primitives which use less data than objects. Collections will always implicitly convert a primitive into its wrapper type when stored.

You could have your array index represent the screen id, and the value stored at the index could be another array or collection which stores the associated user ids.

Comment: A HashMap will work. The original table has duplicate user ids but the idea is for the key to be the user id, and for my value for each key to be an array list of screen ids.

Answer (score 1):

What data type you are using? Let's say to your are using a..

```
Map<Integer,Integer>
```

.then each entry takes 8 bytes (32-Bit) or 16 bytes (64-Bit).. Let's calculate your memory consumption:

8 * 400000 = 3200000 bytes / 1024 = 3125 kbytes / 1024 = 3.05MB

or 6.1MB in case of an 64-Bit data type (like Long)

To say it short.. 3.05 MB or 6 MB is nothing for your hardware.

Even if we calc 3 million entries, we end up with an memory usage of 22 MB (in case of an integer entry set). I don't think a OutofMemory exception is caused by the data size. Check your data type or
switch to MapDB for a quick prototype (supports off-heap memory, see below).

Yes handling 3 000 000 000 entries is getting more seriously. We end up with a memory usage of 22.8 gig. In this case you should consider
a data storage that can handle this amount of data efficiently. I don't think a Java Map (or a vector in another language) is a good use case for such a data amount 
(as Brain wrote, with this amount of data you have to increase the JVM heap space or use MapDB). Also think about your deployment; your product will need 22 gig in memory which 
means high hardware costs. Then the question cost versus in-memory performance has to be balanced... I would go with one of the following alternatives:

- Riak (Key-Value Storage, fits your data structure)
- Neo4J (your data structure can be handled as a net graph; in this case a screen can have multiple relationships to users and versa-vi)
- Or for a quick prototype consider MapDB (http://www.mapdb.org/)
- For a professional and performance solution, you can look at SAP Hana (but its not for free)
- H2 (http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) can be also a good choice. It's an SQL in-memory database.

With one of the solutions above, you can also persist and query your data (without coding indexing, B-trees and stuff). And this is what you want to do, I guess, 
process and operate with your data. At the end only tests can show which technology has the best performance for your needs.

The OutofMemory exception has nothing to do with java or python. Your use case can be implemented in java with no problems.

Comment: Hi @Tom. I was using Map<Integer,ArrayList> as for each user I need to store the number of screens he visited.

Comment: Yes Map<Integer,ArrayList> is the right approach, if you really like to keep your data in-memory. To get rid of the memory exception, try MapDB, if you dont like to extend your JVM heap. It's easy to implement and behaves exactly like a Java Map (and you can persists your data).

Comment: However, you're handling an m:n data model (in the relational database world); best practise might be to have one table with screens (unique id), another with users (unique id) and another with the relationship between both (user + screen id). As far as i can remember Riak is also supporting an Key -> List type (the way you already do it), but Riak is more effective in handle mass of data.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking on the data structure. You have a two dimensional matrix indexed by user-id and screen-id containing a single boolean value, whether it was visisted by that user or not: `visited[screen-id, user-id]`

In the case each user visits almost every screen, the optimal representation would be a set of bits. This means you need `400k x 200k` bits, which is roughly 10G bytes. In Java I would use a BitSet and linearize the access, e.g. `BitSet.get(screen-id + 400000 * user-id)`

If each user only visits a few screens, then there are a lot of repeating false-values in the bit set. This is what is called a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). Actually, this is a well researched problem in computer science and you will find lots of different solutions for it.

This answers your original question, but probably does not solve your problem. In the comment you stated that you want to look up for the users that visited a specific screen. Now, that's a different problem domain, we are shifting from efficient data representation and storage to efficient data access.

Looking up the users that visited a set of screens, is essentially the identical problem to, looking up the documents that contain a set of words. That is a basic information retrieval problem. For this problem, you need a so called *inverted index* data structure. One popular library for this is Apache Lucene.

You can read in the visits and build a a data structure by yourself. Essentially it is a map, addressed by the screen-id, returning a set of the affected users, which is: `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`. For the set of integers the first choice would be a HashSet, which is not very memory efficient. I recommend using a high performance set library targeted for integer values instead, e.g. [IntOpenHashSet](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/download/hppc/0.4.1/api/com/carrotsearch/hppc/IntOpenHashSet.html). Still this will probably not fit in memory, however, if you use Spark you can split your processing in slices and join the processing results later.